# DIV alignment using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have these three boxes: [image]

I want Box 3 to get up under Box 1. How can I do this with CSS?

I'm using bootstrap.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"> .. content .. </div>
    <div class="col-md-6"> .. content .. </div>
    <div class="col-md-6"> .. content .. </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide complete code snippet or external code link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="row col-md-12">
    <div class="row col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-12"> .. Box 1 .. </div>
        <div class="col-md-12"> .. Box 3 .. </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6"> .. Box 2.. </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Haha no problem mate :)